# Java Anonymous Interface implementation in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I want to convert following java Anonymous Interface implementation in Ruby. I am new to Ruby coding.

```
DiscoveryHandler discoveryHandler = new DiscoveryHandler() {
    List<DiscoveredPrinter> printers = new ArrayList<DiscoveredPrinter>();

    public void foundPrinter(DiscoveredPrinter printer) {
        printers.add(printer);
    }

    public void discoveryFinished() {
        for (DiscoveredPrinter printer : printers) {
            System.out.println(printer);
        }
        System.out.println("Discovered " + printers.size() + " printers.");
    }

    public void discoveryError(String message) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred during discovery : " + message);
    }
};
```

Where DiscoveryHandler is an Java Interface which has three methods in it.
1. foundPrinter()
2. discoverFinished()
3. discoveryError()
which I think, should be overridden when its instance (in above case discoveryHandler) is created. I am not sure.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am working with jRuby. How can I create an object of DiscoveryHandler in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the interface has just one method (or its a Java 8 functional one) you can implement it simply by using a block on a place were a method takes a `DiscoveryHandler` as its last argument e.g. :

```
someJavaObject.registerHandler do |printer| # foundPrinter(printer)
  printers.add printer # assuming registerHandler(DiscoveryHandler)
end
```

its also possible to implement multiple interfaces methods using a single block, in which case you get the Java method name as the first block parameter.

from you sample its not clear what the interface methods are and you seem to be it seems that you do not have a use case for the JRuby block-to-iface conversion, esp. since you're holding a state.

Comment: This is working for me I guess. But shows that printers is undefined local variable. It worked for methods. But you see in my code there is a variable printers which is an array, gives as undefined. Please help.

Comment: that is what my notes tried to explain - if you need to hold the `printers` state per handler instance than do not use this code, the other answer is better. I have assumed `printers` is defined outside the block. if you're new to Ruby you need to provide a lot of details around what you're trying to achieve (for next time).